# .POSTs in a for loop are not returning in the same order as they were sent

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm doing several .post calls inside of a forloop.  The return data from the .post is being appended to a div container.  The data that is being looped over is sorted.  I am expecting the post calls to return the data in the same order as I sent them.  But this is not the case...

```
for(i = 0; i<data.length;i++){
    $.post('test.php',{variables},function(data1){
                $('#wrapper').append(data1);
            });
}
```

Is there any way to get the .post to return in the same order?

Comment: Is it possible to place the responses into extra html-elements (e.g. `span`/`div`)? If so, you could create those elements while the loop runs, and have each post-callback write it's appropriate element.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX is asynchronous.

If you want them to be called in order, then you have to wait for the ajax call to complete and then call the next one.

---

You could try  putting it into a [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/):

```
var $q = $({});

for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    $q.queue(function(next){
        $.post('test.php',{variables},function(data1){
            $('#wrapper').append(data1);
            next(); //call next fn
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is this efficient?  Should I not put the .posts in a forloop?

Comment: @AH the queue will run one after another on the `next()` call.